# How to inspect gmail menu dropdown using appium inspector

Tags: selenium, appium, appium-desktop

[image]

Every time I try to inspect the `dropdown` option on the right corner, it is hovering and I can not get the `xpath` or class id, how would i inspect the `dropdown` option.

[image]

Comment: Code trials? Errors?

Comment: Hello @DebanjanB  I have added another picture where it shows that the whole portion is hovering and I can't select the dropdown and inspect

Answer (score 0):

You can see it on right the selector like Id and Xpath. I don't want to attach picture it easy to describe.

[image]

Apart from this, You can try with Chrome inspector. Check details [here](https://developers.google.com/web/tools/chrome-devtools/device-mode)

Comment: Perfect. Please accept it as answer if serve your purpose.it can help people in future with similar issues.